# angular2 timer goes into infinity

Tags: angular, ionic2

**UPDATE**: Plunkr link: https://plnkr.co/edit/NkLUPWH3yNHrPjvYoYdE?p=info

What I am trying to do:
On my template I am populating icons in three columns from three lists one after another each at a second. For that I have three lists of icons in my component. There are some other conditions of changing color of icons at specific level and specific round of a level. Start() is called on a **start** button click and it calls iterator() which handles the icon population logic. The timer should stop when the icons from the list are finished or when the user clicks stop button.

In iterator() function I have a timer that calls the same function at every two seconds. The timer should stop when all the array items are covered but it is not working correctly.

My HTML

```
    <div class="col col1" align="center">
        <div class="ionicon1">
            <ion-icon name="{{current_symbol_for_list1}}" [ngClass]="{'makeBlue': makeBlue1, 'makeRed': makeRed1}"></ion-icon>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col2" align="center">
        <div class="ionicon2">
            <ion-icon name="{{current_symbol_for_list2}}" [ngClass]="{'makeBlue': makeBlue2, 'makeRed': makeRed2}"></ion-icon>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col3" align="center">
        <div class="ionicon3">
            <ion-icon name="{{current_symbol_for_list3}}" [ngClass]="{'makeBlue': makeBlue3, 'makeRed': makeRed3}"></ion-icon>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

My component

```
level= 1;
round=1
ionicon_class_list=[
'alarm', 'android', 'apple', 'radio-button-on', 
'basket', 'beer', 'radio-button-on', 'boat', 
'book', 'bowtie']

current_symbol_for_list=''
current_symbol_for_list1=''
current_symbol_for_list2=''
current_symbol_for_list3=''

myCounter: any;
i=0;
length = this.ionicon_class_list.length;

start(){

    this.iterator(this.i)

}
iterator(){

    if(this.level==1 || this.level==3 || this.level==5 || this.level==6 ){


        /* Handle at Level 1 for all the 3 rounds*/
        if(this.level==1 && this.round==1 && this.current_symbol_for_list2=='apple'){
            this.makeBlue2=true;
        }
       else if(this.level==1 && this.round==1 && this.current_symbol_for_list2=='radio-button-on'){
            this.makeBlue2=false  
        }
        ...

        /* Middle list will have the 'dot' symbol */
        this.current_symbol_for_list2=this.ionicon_class_list[this.i]
        this.current_symbol_for_list1=this.ionicon_class_fake_list1[this.i]
        this.current_symbol_for_list3=this.ionicon_class_fake_list2[this.i]


        if(++this.i<this.length) {
            console.log("i "+ this.i)

            /* Implement timer that runs the same iterator function after 1 second*/
            this.timer = Observable.timer(1000,2000);
            this.myCounter = this.timer.subscribe(
                t => {
                    this.iterator();    
                });
        }

        else if(this.i>=this.length){
            this.myCounter.unsubscribe();
            this.current_symbol_for_list2=null
            this.current_symbol_for_list1=null
            this.current_symbol_for_list3=null
            this.i=0
        }

}
```

Somehow this time doesn't stop and goes into infinity. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please explain exactly what you're trying to achieve ? I'm sure there's a simple solution but having only the code is not really helping in this case :)

Comment: I did update my anwser with a Plunkr. Let me know what you think about it ;)

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you're trying to do here, but this :

```
this.myCounter = this.timer.subscribe(t => {
    this.iterator();    
});
```

is where your problem is coming from.

You subscribe, and subscribe, and subscribe again.

The subscription stays open. It's not a one time thing. So you should refactor your code to take that into account.

**EDIT based on what you asked in a (removed) answer :**

I created a Plunkr, that display a list of icons (font-awesome) every second :
http://plnkr.co/edit/3UVP4359nqUdjm6vlQJp?p=preview

Let me know if you were looking for something like that.

Comment: Subscribe/Unsubscribe have to do nothing with iteration call.

Comment: You have a function `iterator` that trigger a `timer`. Which means, when you call that function one, the timer begins after 1s and ticks every 2s. BUT, in this timer, you call the same function. Which subscribe. Again. And again. And again. So yes, this have to do with the iteration call.

Comment: And BTW, as you reassign your class variable `this.myCounter` at every call, you loose many subscriptions here and you'll end up with memory leaks.

Comment: Hi! it looks promising, I am also updating my question with my own plunkr. I will write you once again once it's finished

Comment: Hi this is my plunkr link: https://plnkr.co/edit/NkLUPWH3yNHrPjvYoYdE?p=info  there is a lot of code (perhaps unnecessary) but then it is easier to figure out the problem. It's a small reflex game. The logic is in my question

Answer (score 0):

I replaced timer with timeout as following:

```
/* Logic to call the iterator() function at every one second */
            if(++this.i < this.length){
                this.timeoutId = setTimeout(()=>{
                    this.iterator()
                }, 1000)
            }

            else if(this.i >= this.length){

                this.current_symbol_for_list1=''
                this.current_symbol_for_list2=''
                this.current_symbol_for_list3=''
                this.i=0
                this.disableStart=false
                this.disableStop=true
                this.failurePrompt='Zeit abgelaufen! Versuchen Sie es noch einmal!'

            }
```